# How to reference v2.0.0 of a Go package that doesn't adhere to the major sub folder convention as a module

Tags: go, go-modules

We are running a spike to determine how or indeed if we can migrate our stack to Go modules.  We depend on v2.0.0 https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/jwt but it is neither converted to a module itself nor does it adhere to the Go convention of putting major versions under sub-folders.

What are our options here when it come to converting our internal package to a module that has this dependency?

Comment: Have you asked the package authors to provide the package in Go module and version form?

Comment: Not yet. I'm hoping a mixed model is somehow possible so that package authors can migrate in their own time..otherwise we are bound by every single one of our direct and indirect dependencies as I currently understand it?

Comment: It IS a go module, with latest tag v2.0.0. Just import "github.com/gbrlsnchs/jwt/v2" (you just call it by `jwt`) in their github they have an example.
Or I didn't understand your question...

Answer (score 1):

`github.com/gbrlsnchs/jwt` at `v2.0.0` has a `go.mod` file that indicates that its canonical import path is [`github.com/gbrlsnchs/jwt/v2`](https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/jwt/blob/808efa0714baff8c25cc65ef8681966740beb9f9/go.mod#L1).

Update your `import` statements to use that path — which should also work in GOPATH mode in Go 1.9.7, 1.10.3, 1.11.0, and above using “[minimal module compatibility](http://golang.org/wiki/Modules#how-are-v2-modules-treated-in-a-build-if-modules-support-is-not-enabled-how-does-minimal-module-compatibility-work-in-197-1103-and-111)” — and you should be good to go.